# Microsoft Team Explorer & TFS: How to open ps1 with ISE?

Tags: tfs, team-explorer

Currently I am experimenting with Microsoft Team Explorer and TFS server. I have several PowerShell scripts checked in.

Is there a way to control which editor Visual Studio launches when double clicking on a checked out file? I would like to start ISE. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself, here are the steps:

1. Go to Tools => External Tools
2. Add new item pointing to C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell_ise.exe
3. Ensure the arguments field contains $(ItemPath)
4. Go to Tools => Options => Keboard (ensure show all settings is checked)
5. Assign a keyboard shortcut to Tools.ExternalCommand1

Now you are able to directly open your script with ISE if its checked out and opened in Visual Studio's internal editor.